# 2D Sidescroller camera

Tags: opengl, java, 2d, side-scroller

I'm using OpenGL. For my tiles, I'm using a display list and I'm just using immediate more for my player (for now). When I move the player, I want to center him in the center of the window, but allow him to jump around on the y axis and not have the camera follow him. But the problem is, is that I can't figure out how to center the player in the viewport! Here is the player update method:

```
public void update() {
    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_D)) {
        World.scrollx -= Constants.scrollSpeed;
        setCurrentSprite(Sprite.PLAYER_RIGHT);
    }
    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A)) {
        World.scrollx += Constants.scrollSpeed;
        setCurrentSprite(Sprite.PLAYER_LEFT);
    }
    move((Constants.WIDTH) / 2  + -World.scrollx, getY());
}
```

World.scrollx and World.scrolly are variables that I increase/decrease to move the tiles. move() is just a method that sets the player position, nothing else. I render the player at his current coordinates like this:

```
public void render() {
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    Shape.renderSprite(getX(), getY(), getCurrentSprite());
    glEnd();
}
```

Shape.renderSprite is this:

```
public static void renderSprite(float x, float y, Sprite sprite){
    glTexCoord2f(sprite.x, sprite.y + Spritesheet.tiles.uniformSize());
    glVertex2f(x, y);
    glTexCoord2f(sprite.x + Spritesheet.tiles.uniformSize() , sprite.y + Spritesheet.tiles.uniformSize());
    glVertex2f(x + Constants.PLAYER_WIDTH, y);
    glTexCoord2f(sprite.x + Spritesheet.tiles.uniformSize(), sprite.y);
    glVertex2f(x + Constants.PLAYER_WIDTH, y + Constants.PLAYER_HEIGHT);
    glTexCoord2f(sprite.x, sprite.y);
    glVertex2f(x, y + Constants.PLAYER_HEIGHT);
}
```

Pretty simple, I just render the quad at the current player's position. This is how I actually render everything:

```
public void render(float scrollx, float scrolly) {
    Spritesheet.tiles.bind();
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(scrollx, scrolly, 0);
    glCallList(tileID);
    glPopMatrix();
    player.render();
}
```

This is the part I'm confused on. I translate the tiles according to the scrollx and scrolly variables, and then I render the player at his current position. But the player moves faster than the tiles scroll, and he can escape out the side of the screen! How do I center the player with moving tiles?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why are you even using immediate mode? and all the deprecated functions, you shouldn't do that.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, did I ask for anyone's opinion on what I should be using? No. Of course I shouldn't be using immediate mode. But you know what, this is just a personal project and I don't feel like dealing with buffer objects right now considering this was supposed to only last for about a week. I find it annoying that people need to comment on that every time I ask for help, but don't answer my question. Thanks for pointing out the obvious yet again.

Comment: Well, I didn't know that. You could write a little comment in the bottom of your question saying "I know you shouldn't use the deprecated functions, but I'm only using them to be able to make my small projects faster". - Okay this comes from a really experienced OpenGL programmer, you should really start making some functions and/or classes to do all your dirty work. That way when creating textures, VBOs, VAOs, Matrix Stack, etc. It will be nice and clean in your small project.

Comment: I have already started creating my own wrapper library. To be perfectly honest with you, I don't think this is relevant at all to my issue. Its my decision to use deprecated functions, and it doesn't matter in this instance because side scrollers can be made in the fixed function or programmable pipeline.

Comment: As said, you did state that you knew it was deprecated in the question. Therefore I said it, as there actually exist a lot of people using the fixed-function pipeline without knowing it's deprecated. Also, even though that a game is capable of using the fixed-function pipeline, doesn't mean you should, there a reason for that it's deprecated... When something is deprecated it means that you shouldn't use it, and that it probably isn't available in the future. Graphics Cards should support the old functions, but don't have to, so your game might not work on some modern graphics cards.

Comment: Did you at all read my above comment? Its my choice to to use deprecated functions. I've been working with OpenGL for a few years now, but I chose to use the fixed function pipeline because its MY project. I have no idea why I would ever want to distribute it, therefore telling me that I shouldn't use deprecated functions because they may not be supported on certain graphics cards is pointless. Now please, let's not fill up the comments with arguing.

Comment: You should not base the x and y position of your player in the `glVertex`, i.e remove those x,y and replace it all by 0. Then you can only worry on the `glTranslate` side